# Initialize shared_ptr passed by member function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I hope someone can help me how to deal with this situation. Here the issue. 
I have a shared library (.so, .dll, .dynlib). Within that library there is some sort of factory class that creates objects. For example my method looked like this:

```
class RenderSystem {
    public:
        int createTexture(Texture** texture, ...);
        ....
}
```

The `createTexture` method in the `RenderSystem` class looks like this:

```
int createTexture(Texture** texture, ...) {
    ....
    *texture = new ...
    return someErrorCode;
}
```

It was creating the `Texture` instance and passing the pointer to the `texture` parameter. We know that the instances created within a shared library has to be destroyed in the same. So I had methods that was deleting/destroying those textures.

I like to use `shared_ptr` for all this but I have to keep the return value as integer. What is the correct way return a `std::shared_ptr<Texture>` without changing the return type of the method. Is it safe to pass a reference to a `std::shared_ptr<Texture>` or do I have to change the return value of the method into `std::shared_ptr<Texutre>`? So is it OK to do this:

```
int createTexture(std::shared_ptr<Texture>& texture, ...) {
    ....
    texture = std::shared_ptr<....>(...) or std::make_shared<...>(..);
    return someErrorCode;
}
```

Hope I could describe the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to pass a reference...?

Yes, it is not uncommon to use the technique you describe, it is often known as *return by reference* (or *[call-by-reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#call-by-reference)*).

With some systems and conventions, the return by reference arguments are at the end of the method signature - but this is a preference and makes little difference.

> ... or do I have to change the return value of the method...?

Alternatives that require a change in the return type are:

- Expanding the return type to be a `std::tuple` or `std::pair` of some sort.
- Possibly the best would be to return the `std::shared_ptr` and throw an exception on the error condition.

The alternatives would require a change in the return type, this is not exactly what you asked for, but alternatives worth mentioning.